# How to add seekbar in tablerow programmatically?

Tags: android, tablerow, android-seekbar

I have a table layout in which i want to add seekbar in each row, programmatically. How can i do that...?  I already have the xml layout for seekbar, but how to add it in tablerow **programmatically**?

EDIT : I would also like to display the divider values, like if the max value assigned to seekbar is 5, then i would like to display, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5 below the seekbar.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
     TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
        tr.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        /* Create a SeekBar to be the row-content. */
      SeekBar seekBar = new SeekBar(this);
            seekBar.setMax(15);
    //      seekBar.setIndeterminate(true);

            ShapeDrawable thumb = new ShapeDrawable(new OvalShape());

            thumb.setIntrinsicHeight(80);
            thumb.setIntrinsicWidth(30);
            seekBar.setThumb(thumb);
            seekBar.setProgress(1);
            seekBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            seekBar.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);

            LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(200, 50);
            seekBar.setLayoutParams(lp); 
   seekBar.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

Comment: I have added the seekbar, but its size is small. How to increase the size of it?

Comment: I have read that layout_weight is used to make seekbar visible properly. Will it be useful in this case??